# Determine whether mouse is always on the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I determine whether mouse is always on the bottom of the viewport? Let us assume that by bottom we mean the bottom 100 pixels of a given page (on a long scrolling page).

this is an example, check the arrow
http://discover.store.sony.com/tablet/#design/weight-distribution

Comment: Define "always", and what do you want to do if this is the case? Tell us what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy!

Calculate how much of that "bottom" area is showing in the current window with window.screen.height and document.height.

Then use onmousemove event to calculate if the mouse is stepping over that area.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank div with the dimensions that you want, use CSS to position:absolute; it on the bottom and z-index it above the other elements, then create a onHover to detect if the mouse is there

**EDIT**

This might work as a solution to avoid using CSS method above (untested)

```
$(function(){
  $.mousemove(function(e){
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    var yMouse = e.pageY;
    if(yMouse > (wHeight - 100)) {
      // Do something
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: yes, but that blocks links underneath the div. I need to detect it on mouse move

Comment: your code works only on page that fits the viewport, i'm talking about a long page with long scroll

Comment: as per [JQuery height() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/) it says $(window).height() gives the dimensions of the browser viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved myself based on Pastor Bones code:
you have to calculate the window scrolltop

```
var scrollT = $(window).scrollTop() + wHeight;
```

so:

```
$(function(){
  $.mousemove(function(e){
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollT = $(window).scrollTop() + wHeight;
    var yMouse = e.pageY;
    if(yMouse > (scrollT - 100)) {
      // Do something
    }
  });
});
```